# Sandcastle in Visual Studio 2022 not generating complete help file information from XML Comments file

Tags: visual-studio, sandcastle

I have set up a project in Visual Studio to generate an XML comments file from my C# XML comments (/// items).  It generates the XML file correctly.  I have also created a Sandcastle Help File Builder project that is supposed to create HTML help files that contain the information in the XML Comments file.  However, it is not producing all the member information I am entering.

For example, shown below is the XML comment information for the method DisplayList.

```cs
        /// <summary>
        /// Display an IEnumerable list on the Console screen
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="horizontal">bool</param>
        /// <para>
        /// <c>true</c> to print the list horizontally;
        ///  <c>false</c> to print vertically.
        /// </para>
        /// <param name="myList">IEnumerable</param>
        /// <para>The IEnumerable list to display.</para>
        /// <param name="separationOrIndentString">string</param>
        /// <para>
        /// If <c>horizontal</c> is <c>true</c>, contains the separation string;
        ///  else, contains the indentation string.
        /// </para>
        public static void DisplayList (bool horizontal,
                                        IEnumerable myList,
                                        string separationOrIndentString)
```

Here is the XML information that was produced by Visual Studio.
[Part of XML Comments file MyLibrary.XML](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EUBne.png)

Shown below is the HTML help for this method that was generated by the Sandcastle Help File Builder tool in Visual Studio.

[HTML Help Information Generated by Sandcastle](https://i.stack.imgur.com/C9HEE.png)

As you can see, it is very sparse and doesn't have my  or  entries.

Also, when I look at the SandCastle log file, it has an entry that says:
Ignoring duplicate comments file 'C:\Users\Admin\source\repos\MyLibrary\MyLibrary\bin\Debug\net8.0\MyLibrary.xml'

I don't know what it means by that.  There is no duplicate MyLibrary.xml file that I can find.

How do I fix this problem?
My email address is nickajp@comcast.net

I pretty much described what I did and what I expected above.